# Why do SVG tag is not working as expected

Tags: html, svg

Could you please check if my SVG has a valid format ? Coz I'm trying to integrate it on my HTML page, but it's showing me a SVG tag with 0px height and 0px width ...

```html
<svg class="dv lineChart" height="100" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 3 2">
        <path stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" d="M 0 0 L 0 1 L 1 0 L 2 0 L 3 2 L 3 0 Z"></path>
    </svg>
```

Comment: `viewBox` should have a capital `B`. Apart from that it looks OK. Can you edit your question to add a [mcve] using the snippet editor?

Comment: @r3mainer I already tried this ... no difference, and I'm building this tag with javascript (setAttribute viewBox), should I use setAttributeNS

Comment: If you're building it with code, show us the code. Presumably you're using createElement where you should be using createElementNS